# Oracle update, make ~24000 changes

Tags: sql, oracle, sql-update

I want to make a query or some function in Oracle what can update ~24000 rows. For example 1 update query looks like this:

```
update numbers
set status = 1 and some_id = 123123
where number_id = 1231;
```

"some_id" and "number_id" are different in every query.

Problem is doing this one by one is taking too much time, I need quicker solution.

Comment: some_id and status are taking value from where ?

Answer (score 3):

Put the varying values into a table and then use that in your query:

```
update numbers n
set status=1, 
    some_id = (select some_id from newtable t where t.number_id = n.number_id)
where number_id in (select number_id from newtable);
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks as if you had hard-wired the predicates and update values in your query. You might be able to improve performance quite a bit by using bind variables. With bind variables, Oracle only needs one hard-parse for all 24k identical SQL UPDATE statements, instead of 24k hard-parses (and update execution plans) for 24k distinct SQL UPDATE statements.

With Java:

```
update numbers
set status = ?, some_id = ?
where number_id = ?;
```

With other tools:

```
update numbers
set status = :1, some_id = :2
where number_id = :3;
```

Answer (score 0):

Write a PL-SQL stored procedure and pass in the parameters.  Call it once and be done.

Or use `PreparedStatement` and batch your requests.

They probably take too long because you do a round trip for each one.  Batch will help a great deal, because you'll only do one round trip.